# Handle submit of a form that inside of a included jsp with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use:

```
...
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
...
<div id="list">
  <jsp:include page="list.jsp" />
  //form was here
</div>
...
```

to handle my form's submit and it works. I can handle my form's submit.

However I moved my form into the `list.jsp` but I think that it can't recognize it inside of an jsp file so I can't handle my form's submit. I want that ability within `list.jsp` too.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided, it looks like you are trying to attach the event to the form before it's rendered. Wrap the event binding in an onready function.

```
$(function(){
   $("#form").submit(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

If this is what you are doing, make sure that the form rendered by the `jsp` include has an `id="form"`.